# Creating File On Full Disk

Tags: c#

Is it possible to create a file on a disk which is full??

Does creation of the file take any space??

Basically I am seeing a case where C# has created but failed to write anything whhich I think points to a full disk.

Does anyone know whether creating a file on a full disk will fail or not??

This wa done using c# o Windw xSerevr- The log file was also written to the same drive

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but for your case at hand, is checking the available space beforehand not an option?

Comment: @Pekka: Checking the space beforehand *might* work in most cases, but it is not safe. This is a classical scenario for exceptions. What if the free space has been consumed by someone else between the check and the actual IO operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating (empty) files should still be possible in most cases. The MFT is a separate part of the volume which won't get used for file data.

It should even be possible to store small amounts of data without needing more than the file entry in the MFT. NTFS can store streams as ["resident data"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntfs#Resident_vs._non-resident_data_streams) in the stream descriptor which doesn't need any additional space, but only works for very small files.

I think your issue is another problem, though. It may be that you have permissions to create a file but not to write anything to it. You might want to check the ACLs of the location where you're trying to write.

Comment: Actual file data in the MFT? Never knew that. Seems very odd :)

Comment: Thorarin: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntfs#Resident_vs._non-resident_data_streams ... got that slightly wrong, though. I'll correct.